# I can't position my div and radio button

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position the text that says Male and a radio button next to it but somehow they don't stand next to each other... But they(text Gender included) also have to be in the same line. Problem solved, if anyone else is having trouble with my ex problem here is how you do it. :)

```
.genderM {
            position: fixed;
            left: 175px;
            top: 130px;
        }
.genderF{
            position:fixed;
            top: 130px;
            left: 245px;
        }

<div class="genderM">Male 
    <input type="radio" id="gender" name="genderrr" />
    </div>
    <div class="genderF">Female
    <input type="radio" id="gender" name="genderrr" />
    </div>
```

Comment: can you change your html structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First `div` is block level element. Block level elements occupies the entire space(create new line). You can include your radio in the `div` element. Second avoid inline styles, use class instead. Additionally you can remove `br />` and add for example `margin-bottom: 60px`:

```css
.rdGender {
  position: fixed;
  left: 175px;
}
.genderCont {
  padding-left: 110px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.genderSubmitBtn {
  position: fixed;
  left: 125px;
}
```

```html
Gender:
<div class="genderCont">Male
  <input type="radio" id="gender" />
</div>

<input type="submit" class="genderSubmitBtn" value="Submit" id="submit" />
```

Comment: But it still looks crooked?

Comment: @AltayMazlum what do you mean crooked? In your OP _I'm trying to position the text that says Male and a radio button next to it_ .

Answer (score 0):

div is block level level element. Use span instead. But still it's better to use label while combining with input fields something like below:

```
<div>
   <label>Gender: </label>
   <label for="male">male</label>
   <input type="text" name="male" id="male" />
   <label for="female">female</label>
   <input type="text" name="female" id="female" />
</div>
```

And you can style to label for eg:

```
label{
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Uhm you wrote <input type="text"> over there but it should be radio so i'll just change it to radio right?

Answer (score 0):

I had made a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/2f03jssu/1/
plz check this.
This is because of the div that is closed first.

```
Gender: <div style="padding-left:110px">Male <input type="radio" id="gender" style="position:fixed; left: 175px;" /></div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" style="position: fixed; left: 125px;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
Gender: Male <input type="radio" id="gender" style="position:fixed; left: 175px;" />
</div>
<br />    <br />    <br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" style="position: fixed; left: 125px;" />
```

Note: If a HTML Element is included in a div-tag, it takes the entire horizontal space. You can use span-tag instead.